# Aim at verb+ING vs Aim to verb

Tags: verbs, idioms, phrasal-verbs

In a book about the philosopher Collingwood, I have found the following statement about logic. At first glance, it seems to me that the change from *aim to* to *aim at* is merely stylistic, but I think that it could also be possible that there might be a certain either grammatical or logical explanation for the difference.

"On the one hand it is descriptive, and **aims to give** an account of how we actually think; on the other hand it is normative, and **aims at giving** an account of the ideal of thought, the way in which we ought to think."

Is the difference merely stylistic?

Comment: The first is simply *indicative verb +infinitive*, the second *indicative verb +at+gerund*. And it applies to all kinds of verbs "tries to/at", "pretends to/at", "hopes to/at", "helps to/at", "fails to/at". Or "succeeds to/ **in**" etc.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, the author makes the change to avoid how boring it would be to use the exact same phrase twice in a row.  The bolded phrases are not different in meaning.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's also a slight difference in meaning. This could be proved by the fact that, otherwise we could use "*to aim* + gerund (representing the substantive action) as the object verb could be replaced by "*it*" (*I'm aiming to it*).

But because the correct and most taught structure (although illogical) is:

> aim at+gerund
> aim to + base verb

Then there must be a further reason besides the stylistic construct.